# Amazon EC2 Micro Instance response time testing

Tags: apache, yii, amazon-ec2, firebug, performance-testing

I am testing Receiving time in Firefox NET tab inside Firebug and receiving time is coming as quite high. Server has Apache , PHP (YII framework) and MYSQL running with only test data. I want to know if this is common observation for Amazon micro instances or is there need for optimization from developers for improving upon this ?

For ex -

```
Size    Receiving Time( Dark Green at end)
200 KB     8.5s
6.7 KB     6.24s
```

Snap is attached as well -

[image: Response time]

Comment: It would be helpful if you had some comparison values from another server. I run Yii on micro instances and have response times in the range of some 100 ms. So it could also be your Yii application which is badly designed and thus slow.

Comment: Processing time in violet looks OK, so no need to bother your code. The green part only represents the time to receive the data, right? Then you may have been very unlucky with that instance or people sharing the same machine are highly exploiting there's. Try to stop/start your instance so that you get a new one and compare. You could also do some DL speed test from your instance to your computer to see what bandwidth you have toward the instance.